# Update the specific value in text file c

Tags: c

I am facing an issue with the last part of the assignment. I want to update(modify) the specific value in a text file but this program stop working from the if statement in the while loop. I have tried to fix this issue but I couldn't figure it out. Please help.

```
int Equant()
{
    DisplayList();
    FILE * fpr_r = fopen("donation.txt", "r");
    FILE * fpr_w = fopen("Edonation.txt", "w");
    if (fpr_r == NULL || fpr_w == NULL)
    {
        printf ("An able to open the file for writing");
        exit(1);
    }
    int Inumber, v=0;
    double NQuant, NVQuant;

    struct Donate Esearch;
    printf ("\nEnter the ID you want to change the quantity: ");
    scanf ("%d", &Inumber);
    
    while (fread(&Esearch, sizeof(struct Donate),1,fpr_r))
    {
        fscanf (fpr_r,"%d %s %s %s %d %lf,", &Esearch.IDd, &Esearch.supply, &Esearch.Scode, &Esearch.Cdonator, &Esearch.Nship, &Esearch.QuantityR);

        if (Esearch.IDd == Inumber) 
        {
            printf ("ID: %d Name of Supply: %s, Supply Code: %s, Donator: %s, No. of Shipment: %d, Quantity Received (Million): %lf\n",
                Esearch.IDd, Esearch.supply, Esearch.Scode, Esearch.Cdonator, Esearch.Nship, Esearch.QuantityR);
            printf ("\nEnter the new  Quantity value: ");
            scanf ("%lf", &NVQuant);
            Esearch.QuantityR = NVQuant;
        }
        fwrite (&Esearch, sizeof(struct Donate),1,fpr_w);
    }
    fclose(fpr_r);
    fclose(fpr_w);
    if (!v)
    {
        printf ("No line founded.\n");
    }
```

Comment: You are mixing `fread` with `fscanf`. Then you aren't writing the text file as text, but binary. You should use `fprintf` to output.

Comment: `fread` and `fscanf` both read from the file. You're ignoring every other item and not checking for success with `fscanf`.

Comment: The input and output are text files, so stop using `fread` and `fwrite`. Control the loop with `while(fscanf( /*etc*/ ) == 6) { ... fprintf ( /*etc*/ ); }`